# How to get this rounded corner effect using only CSS?

Tags: css, angular, sass, rounded-corners, border-radius

This is the design I'm going for:
[design with rounded corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIe0r.png)

And this is what I have implemented so far:
[implementation with blocky segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG4wh.png)

How can I achieve the rounded corners effect on opposite corners, as shown in the intended design? Right now, each of the segments are their own HTML element and are encompassed in a HTML block that does have the rounded corner effect, but it is under the rectangular segments. Is there some sort of clipping that I can do so that the shape of the HTML element under the segments can be superimposed onto the segments so that they have the rounded colors in the right spots (I don't want the breaks between colors to be rounded also)?

This is in angular, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `border-radius` on the parent + `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `border-radius` to achieve this.

```css
#myBar {
  background: #6f00ff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBar">
<!-- your content-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use these styles (change 20px with what works for you.)

for left most segment

```
.left-round {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
```

for right most segment

```
.right-round {
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

Keep your rest of the code as it is.

**Example**

[image]

```css
.left-round {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.right-round {
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row>div {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="red left-round">Test</div>
  <div class="green">col 2</div>
  <div class="blue right-round">col 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

You can style your left most segment with

```
border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
```

and your right most segment with

```
border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
```

The second way would be to place all the three segments inside a div and style the div with

```
border-radius: 25px;
```

Answer (score -1):

Code sample if you just need one element to have all three colors.

HTML Code

```
<div id="colorBar">
  <!-- Example div with hello inside to display CSS-->
    hello
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
#colorBar{
  /* Creates rounded corners for element */
  border-radius: 15px;
  /* linear-gradient has color ,starting percentage, and ending percentage*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
     blue 0% 33%, purple 33% 66%, lightblue 66% 100%);
}
```

[Example of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToEP4.png)